# React .map not re-rendering on state change in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [fullProductCostingDataState, setFullProductCostingDataState] = useState([]);

// update of state done here

{fullProductCostingDataState.map((item, index) => {
     return (
         <p key={index}>{item["materialName"]}</p>
     )
})}
```

Sorry I know this is a potentially stupid question but I know the .map function is only rendered once and then even if the state changes the data is not re-mapped to the page but how do I solve this as I need it to list the items in the state. All replies I found online mention using render() but I'm using a functional component so don't have render, can I use hooks to force it to update or is .map completely the wrong thing to be using for this.

```
function ItemRow(props) {
    let data = props.fullData;
    let newItem = { "id": props.id, "materialName": props.name, "value": totalPrice }
    data.push(newItem);
    props.setFullData(data);
}
```

That's a watered-down version of how I'm updating the state (the full version has a lot of if statements in to check for various things and remove duplicates), guessing I'm mutating it?

Comment: If it's not re-rendering it's probably because you've mutated state. If it's re-rendering but in a wrong/weird way, it's because you're using the `index` as a `key` - don't use array indicies as key unless the sort order of the array is 100% guaranteed never to change (and even then, just use a different, unique-r key)

**Show us where/how you're updating the state**

Comment: Can you add the full source code? Seems like your state itself isn't getting updated.

Comment: I think you forgot to write `return`  in the line having `map`, also you should remove curly braces around that. so it will be `return fullProductCostingDataState.map ...` only.

Comment: *I know the .map function is only rendered once and then even if the state changes the data is not re-mapped to the page*.. are you sure about this? Basically you assume it's impossible that there's a bug in the code *you* wrote. It must be because of some magical implementation behind the rendering and behind `map` that only runs once. No, there's no mystical code behind it, your component is a function, it gets called like any other function `myFn()`, and **everything** in the body of the function runs again. You should provide the full code.

Comment: Edited my post with how I'm updating the state, I'm pretty sure it's updating as I have a button at the bottom of the page that does console.log(fullProductCostingDataState) and that's always correct when clicked.

Comment: `data.push` is mutating the state. Since `fullData` is an object (not a primitive) doing `data = fullData` you're just passing the reference to the same object, and not copying it

Comment: I knew it would be a stupid mistake. Will have to understand mutating and find a way to fix it. The biggest thing I struggled with was removing an item from the array completly.

Comment: In your case, if you want to *add* a new item in an array, you can just do `setFullData([...data, newItem]`, and if you want to *remove* an item just use `filter`. This way you're returning a new array. (careful though, because the objects in the new array are still the original ones, so if you need to modify an object in the array, then you need to copy the object first)

Comment: I think the curly braces in return was what was breaking me after a couple state changes. Sure I had an extra unnecessary statement in one of the braces. But why should any of this matter? But thank you @ShivamSharma !

Answer (score 3):

Solved it thanks to everyone's help on here.

Changed `let data = props.fullData;`
to
`let data = [...props.fullData];`
then edited the data variable before calling the set state function using the data variable :)

Thanks everyone,

Answer (score 0):

```
const [fullProductCostingDataState, setFullProductCostingDataState] = useState([]);

// update of state done here

useEffect(()=>{},[fullProductCostingDataState]) // this will solve your issue 

{fullProductCostingDataState?.map((item, index) => {
     return (
         <p key={index}>{item["materialName"]}</p>
     )
})}
```

Your issue will be solved as useEffect re-render the page when the state is changed.
Now you just have to update the state.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work pretty sure my state updating is the culprit.